# How should I handle an OP and a question with rude and pointless commentary?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

*[WordPress is not respecting Docker environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633163/wordpress-not-respecting-docker-environment-variables)* came in yesterday and had a lot of rude commentary on WordPress which I cleaned up (it doesn't serve the OP's interest and doesn't help anyone provide an answer).

I went back in today to check on the question and noticed that the user had roll backed my edits (I didn't know this was a privilege we all had). The OP added further negative commentary in their question. [e-net4-the-harassed-curator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-the-harassed-curator) came in to lend a hand and also clean up abusive language. The OP still rolled back that edit.

At this point, I did a rollback to my original edit, but I feel it's a waste of time because the OP will just undo what I did. So, at that point, what can we do other than just hope the question gets closed?

I looked at the OP's history and he's got some pretty angry commentary elsewhere as well. It's actually the first time I see this and am looking for guidance.

Comment: That was an entirely legitimate edit; when the OP doubled down, flag for moderator help, they can lock the question.

Comment: It's best to avoid rollback wars: nobody wins. Jon's advice is good, and the system will auto-flag a post after a few (3 ?) rollbacks have occurred.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the OP added information to the question between edit 2 (the edit you rolled back to) and edit 6 (the most recent non-rollback edit). Make sure not to destroy or remove added information by OP when you rollback to remove things that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Well, at least it has entertainment value: 'delete it and mark whole wordpress as a complete security bug' lol:)

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks for pointing it out, I should have been more careful, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this question would have been solved if others had explained to the user why their commentary in their question was removed? All I see are rollbacks without explanation.

Comment: @yeah22 I wonder about that too. There aren't any comments at all visible currently.

Comment: That wasn't the only problematic question from that user, and I had flagged both questions for moderator attention. The situation was resolved now.

Comment: @yeah22 In my defense, the edits I made had a sufficiently clear reason, as I do most of the time. And seeing the pathetic overreaction that came from this particular user, I can confirm that they read it. Leaving a comment wouldn't have helped one thing.

Comment: @Trilarion My comment above. Edits do not have to be followed by comments. By my experience, they eventually cause harm more often than not.

Comment: @yeah22 - 'explain to user _why_' - should have been obvious to all but the most angry poster - and the most angry poster we don't need here.  IMO.

Comment: Your rollback at [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66633163/9) removed some content from question.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator -> but for the other question at least you/somebody managed to delete it .. thx

Comment: @BashStack To be clear on this: once you started calling me out with your abusive edits, I flagged one of your posts for moderator attention and invited folks at the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) chatroom to vote to delete the question. It wasn't that much because you asked, but to bury the persistent source of trouble that you were causing.

Comment: @BashStack It's standard practice to remove meta-commentary from other users' posts. People _don't earn reputation or other privileges_ for doing it, but it is for the sake of keeping content clean from distractions and generally more useful. As such, calling people out for doing it is not OK (but I imagine you have already been warned about this).

Comment: @E_net4thecurator nope, first time ( Eu sinto Muito )

Comment: @davidbak To be honest, I don't think it would be too obvious to a person why comments such as that would be removed. StackExchange has a collaborative editing environment that is unique compared to other sites. Questions, and answers are structured in a forum-like style, with each individual user being listed as the author. As a result, I can imagine someone objecting to their post being edited - "it's my post, what gives you the right to change it?"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As commented by @jonrsharpe:

> That was an entirely legitimate edit; when the OP doubled down, flag
> for moderator help, they can lock the question.

It looks like you or someone may have flagged the question now because an SO Moderator appears to be investigating and has locked the question.

Comment: BTW saw your edits, thanks! I was tempted to roll back as a recursive point :-) Also wasn't aware there was a meta stackoverflow. Thanks for pointing that out. Do we have tools to migrate Q&As to the right site?

Comment: Here's a Meta SE FAQ on migration: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work  In general, most moderators seem to prefer that users delete and re-ask on the correct site rather than migrate nowadays.

Comment: would have gone for that , but couldnt delete it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to all wasting their time on that.

If it would have been possible I would just have had imrproved the question, or completely removed it.

But I could neither edit nor remove it at the first point ( maybe due to flags?)

So I hoped a rollback would at least help to "make it deleteable" or "editable" ...  a somehow unfair state.

OK, I admit I was in a rage due to that WordCrap, **but when you cannot even clean up yor own question it makes no sense** (to me).

Thanks to whoever made it at least deletable now ....

And double up to "Not suitable for this site".

Comment: Thanks for voicing your side of the story. Some words of advice: don't complain about downvotes in comments. They are not an attack on you. Especially on Meta they work differently. Please, consider using automatic spell checker or at least capital letters when writing a post as this helps us to read it and makes it look more professional.

Comment: Your post was locked for a time to prevent further damage to the post. That may have been why you couldn't edit. Closure by itself does not do that.

Comment: Also, you edited / rolled back before the question was locked so your post here is actually in bad faith.

Comment: well the first rollback was just because it said "somebody edited your thingy" when keeping the editor window open and trying to fix a.k.a. "add debugging information"  .. just reloaded the page ... , rollback ( like ` git reset head ` ) ..  for me defending wordpress is bad faith ... but i get it .. OT ..

Comment: The rollback removing your additional information and then closure because the question lacked that information wasn't great but I think I moderator flag explaining you had added debugging information that was later removed would have worked had things not escalated.